# Rails Nested Attributes pluralization when using associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, paperclip, nested-attributes

To keep things to the point, I have two models: Article & Photos(below). When I use associations i.e. (below), why is photos pluralized? For example, if I did @article.user it would show the user object. I am using Paperclip btw. Is it because the article can have many instances of Photo(multiple rows in the db)???

```
 <% if @article.photos.exists? %>
     <div class="row thumbnailrow">
       <% @article.photos.each do |x| %>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
           <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" class="img-responsive"/>-->
           <%= image_tag x.image.url(:full), :class=> "img-responsive" %>
         </div>
       <% end %>
     </div>
 <% end %> 

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

validates_presence_of :title,length: {minimum: 20, maximum:100}, :message =>" Enter a valid title. Minimum of 20 characters"
validates_presence_of :category, presence: true
#validates_presence_of :content, presence: true, length: {minimum: 500, maximum: 1000}
validates_associated :photos, :message => "Please use a valid image"
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank?} 

def author
    if user.present?
        [user.first_name, user.last_name].reject(&:blank?).join(' ')
    else
        "author name"
    end
end
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :full => "640x480#", :medium => "300x300>",     :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "http://placehold.it/350x200"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

validates :image, :attachment_presence => true


belongs_to :article

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is smart about it's associations so when you tell it that one ActiveRecord model `has_many :photos` it understands that even if there is only one photo attached, there may be more than one.  If you were to change the association to `has_one :photo` it would not longer be plural.  Make sense?